# Get list of CRS in QGIS by python?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, coordinate-system, epsg

It is possible to get list/dictionary of "Recently used coordinate reference system" from QGIS by python?

Or get list of all "Coordinate reference systems of the world" also from QGIS by python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recently used projections are stored in your user settings. Here is an example of the keys and some sample values:

- UI/recentProjections=932, 3452
- UI/recentProjectionsProj4="+proj=aea +lat_1=55 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-154 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs", "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
- UI/recentProjectionsAuthId=EPSG:2964, EPSG:4326

For example, you could get the AuthIds like so:

```py
>>> QSettings().value('UI/recentProjectionsAuthId')
[u'EPSG:4326', u'EPSG:3338', u'EPSG:2964', u'EPSG:900913', u'EPSG:3035', u'EPSG:32733', u'EPSG:4267']
```

All of the coordinate systems are stored in the srs.db file found in the resources directory of your QGIS install. You can use the Python sqlite3 module to query this database and get a list of all the coordinate systems:

```py
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(QgsApplication.srsDbFilePath())
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from vw_srs')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for crs in rows:
  # do something...
  print crs
cur.close()
con.close()
```

**For QGIS 3.x**:

- `srsDbFilePath()` was renamed to `srsDatabaseFilePath()`
- the keys are:

  - `UI/recentProjectionsProj4`
  - `UI/recentProjectionsWkt`
  - `UI/recentProjectionsAuthId`

Comment: How to from QSettings().value('UI/recentProjectionsAuthId') get list? I receive <PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x0D27BB20>

Comment: You must be using QGIS 1.8. Use the ``toString`` method on the QVariant object to extract the string.

Comment: I use toString but string is empty. In 'Project Properties'>>> Recently used coordinate... I have a few entries.These are two different lists? (I use QGIS 1.8)